# How to change the order of HTML output of a core block?

Tags: filters, hooks, block-editor

I want to change the HTML output of the latest-posts block (i.e.: wrap the date inside the post link).

I know I can hook into `'blocks.getSaveElement'` and retrieve stuff like the element, blockType and attributes.

But none of this is helpful as this block is rendered in the front-end via php.
Is the only way to manipulate the markup to create a custom block and copying the core block files? That seems unintuitive and too much work for swapping two tags. And just writing JS to manipulate the front-end is not an option (might make elements jump around).

Any ideas on how to achieve this in any better way?

Comment: Have you looked into the `render_block` filter? Did a quick look through the sources, seems like this is the best option. Though you'd have to manually alter the HTML there.

Comment: I tried that as well. It also does return only the attributes which I could also retrieve via the `getSaveElement` filter. And one does not have access to the inner `<li>` elements attributes with `render_block`.

Comment: Doesn't `render_block` (the PHP filter) return the entire HTML? [Per the source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-block.php#L237) it should have the `$block_content` which is the result of the render method of the individual block

Comment: Not in this case, it only returns the latest-posts outer block. So there is no way of accessing the inner list elements. Also the `"innerHTML"` attribute is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The `render_block` filter works for this - I just tested on a fresh install. However, you'll have to use the final HTML, so it gets a bit ugly.

The following code will copy the first `<a>` tag and wrap the copy around each `<time>` tag in the list.

```
\add_filter('render_block', function($content, $parsed): string {
        // skip other blocks
        if ($parsed['blockName'] !== 'core/latest-posts') {
                return $content;
        }

        // skip latest posts that don't display the date
        if (empty($parsed['attrs']['displayPostDate']) || !$parsed['attrs']['displayPostDate']) {
                return $content;
        }

        $dom = new \DomDocument();
        // parse the HTML, the @ is required because DomDocument
        // doesn't know about HTML5's <time>
        @$dom->loadHTML($content);

        // get each individual post
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $entry) {
                $links = $entry->getElementsByTagName('a');
                if ($links->count() === 0) {
                        continue;
                }

                foreach ($entry->getElementsByTagName('time') as $time) {
                        // clone the first <a>
                        $link = $links->item(0)->cloneNode();
                        // wrap the <time> around that <a>
                        $time->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $time);
                        $link->appendChild($time);
                }
        }

        // $dom->saveHTML() returns false on error
        $newContent = $dom->saveHTML();
        if ($newContent !== false) {
            return $newContent;
        }

        return $content;
}, 10, 2);
```

However, this does not alter the output inside the editor. Since the block is purely rendered in React nowadays, you'd have to use some of the editor filters for that.

Comment: Thank you! It does work, but it is indeed ugly. That shouldn't be the way to handle stuff like that, but I didn't find any other "official" way of doing it. It might be easier to use the wp.data import to grab the entries one needs in a custom block.

Comment: @Unfu I've digged throug the server side code so far and don't think there is a better way. It's been a while since I've worked with the client side filters, but that is out of scope here anyways. And yes, creating a new block is of course always an option - I too have resorted to it when realizing changing core blocks is too troublesome